# RPM's EPOCH, in DEB terms

Tags: deb

In RPM, there is a (much maligned, but nonetheless it is there) field called EPOCH, used to override a version stream with lower numbering.

It is a source of constant trouble, but in the cases where it is needed, EPOCH is often the only way to go.

Does the DEB package format have a similar field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the simple answer is that Debian packages also have an epoch field.

From the policy manual: [version fields](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-f-Version)